# Call LLVM-GCC in PHP

Tags: php, c, gcc, llvm, llvm-gcc

I tried to generate LLVM intermediate code by calling

```
llvm-gcc -emit-llvm -I/mypath/ -c main.c -o main.o
```

It works perfectly without any warnings or errors if I manually type this command in the terminal.

However I have built a website that can automate this process by calling exec function in PHP like below.

```
exec("llvm-gcc -emit-llvm -I/mypath/ -c main.c -o main.o",$msg,$ret);
```

It will still generate .o file with a warning. The warning says that

```
Potential incompatible plugin version. GCC: 4.5.3. Expected: 4.5.4
Defines 'dragonegg_disable_version_check' as env variable to remove this warning.
Please note that unexpected errors might occur.
```

The php command will still return 0, which is successful. However when I run the generated .o file, it will throw invalid bitcode signature error.

The server is running ubuntu and Apache. My llvm-gcc version is 2.9 which uses 4.2.1 gcc.

Any help will do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to update the GCC to 4.5.4. But if you just want to hide the warning, simply define `dragonegg_disable_version_check`.

```php
$command = 'dragonegg_disable_version_check=1'
         . ' llvm-gcc -emit-llvm -I/mypath/'
         . ' -c main.c -o main.o';
exec($command,$msg,$ret);
```

For the `invalid bit code signature` error -- see this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385212/emit-llvm-in-linux).

Comment: I will try to update GCC. But the weird thing is that I can run this command manually without warnings. Why is that?